# Java connection via Globals API causes a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, global, intersystems

I am trying to connect a Java application to an InterSystems Caché database via [Globals API](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV_globals#BXJV_globals_intro).

```
import com.intersys.globals.*;

public class Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String user = "Andrew";
        final String password = "Tobilko";

        Connection connection = ConnectionContext.getConnection();
        connection.connect("USER", user, password);
    }

}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.intersys.globals.internal.GlobalsConnectionJNI.connectImpl(Native Method)
    at com.intersys.globals.internal.GlobalsConnectionJNI.connect(GlobalsConnectionJNI.java:107)
    at com.tobilko.a3.Assignment.main(Assignment.java:12)
```

1. The credentials and the namespace are correct.
2. The Cache instance has been initialised correctly and by instruction.
3. All the global environment variables including `GLOBALS_HOME` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` have been set.
4. The following libraries have been soft-linked:

   ```
   ln -s $GLOBALS_HOME/bin/libisccache.dylib /usr/local/lib
   ln -s $GLOBALS_HOME/bin/liblcbjni.dylib /usr/local/lib
   ln -s $GLOBALS_HOME/bin/liblcbindnt.dylib /usr/local/lib
   ln -s $GLOBALS_HOME/bin/liblcbclientnt.dylib /usr/local/lib
   ln -s $GLOBALS_HOME/bin/libmdsjni.dylib /usr/local/lib
   ```
5. `-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib` has been specified.
6. The jars have been included.

[image]

These steps led me to a `StackOverflowError` exception. 
I have no idea where I could have made a mistake.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DAiMor, could you have a look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skipped the Window configuration part because it isn't my OS.

Apparently, the next configuration is required for all systems:

> ### Configuration for Windows
>
> The default stack size of the Java Virtual Machine on Windows is too small for running eXTreme applications (running them with the
>   default stack size causes Java to report `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW`). To
>   optimize performance, heap size should also be increased.
>
> To
>   temporarily modify the stack size and heap size when running an
>   eXTreme application, add the following command line arguments:
>
> ```
> -Xss1024k -Xms2500m -Xmx2500m
> ```

Increasing the stack size has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, I'm not so familiar with GlobalsAPI. But, I did some research and found that this GlobalsAPI was in previous versions of Java CacheExtreme library `cacheextreme.jar`, in Caché `lib` folder. In version which you tried to use, GlobalsAPI already disappeared, and only Event Persistent still there. And with IRIS this old library will disappear at all. And in [IRIS documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/iris20181/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV) nothing more about GlobalsAPI. I think it would be better if you ask about GlobalsAPI future on the [Developer Community](http://community.intersystems.com/) portal.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I will continue my investigations on their forum.

Comment: btw, I resolved this issue by increasing the stack size. It was mentioned in the configuration for Windows. Though, other problems emerged :)